# Rewrite adminhtml template not working, only if I refresh the page

Tags: blocks, adminhtml, template, overrides, magento-1

I want to modify the backend template `design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/totals.phtml`

Its gonna be part of a module so I've implement the rewrite in the modules layout update file (`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xentas_sales.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <!-- Backend create order -->
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <!-- Overwrite totals template -->    
        <reference name="data">
                <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_totals" name="totals">
                    <action method="unsetChild"><name>totals</name></action>
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>xentas_sales/sales/order/create/totals.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

**But the new template only shows up if I refresh the "create new order" page in backend. It does not show up when I load the page in the first place.**

I experience the same issue if I overwrite `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Totals.php`
and add to its _construct method `setTemplate('...');`

So it looks like there is some kind of sort order issue? How can I override an adminhtml template without creating my own admin theme and make sure its get overwritten by page load and not only by page refresh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change **only template**. There *are no need to change rewrite block class*.

As per as,magento by *reference* `<reference name="">` name you can change template file.So **no need to rewrite block class**.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <!-- Overwrite totals template -->    
        <reference name="totals">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>xentas_sales/sales/order/create/totals.phtml</template>
                    </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

Also there are **two handlers,this phtml are called** ,*so you should need  to changes also there* .

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_totals>
        <reference name="totals">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>xentas_sales/sales/order/create/totals.phtml</template>
                    </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_totals>
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
        <reference name="totals">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>xentas_sales/sales/order/create/totals.phtml</template>
                    </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
```

**Most Important thing**

*You need to  define xentas_sales.xml file at config.xml*

Comment: You are awesome Amit. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Learned a lot. Works perfectly!

Comment: Great shout Amit, had a similar problem with the address templates on create order via admin, your post helped me realise the template was defined multiple times! +1 from me :)